# How to return results from a loop in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I want to see the result displaying dates like this

```
 "2001-01-01 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-02 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-03 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-04 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-05 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-06 00:00:00+05:30"
 "2001-01-07 00:00:00+05:30"
```

so on...
but iam getting error

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM      instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension(date) line 12 at SQL statement
```

can  you tell me what is the issue

function i created

```
create or replace function insert_date_dimension("Date" date)
returns text as
$$
Declare dat date;
start_date date;
end_date date;
Begin
start_date:='2016/01/01';
end_date:='2016/12/31';
while start_date<=end_date 
loop
select start_date;
start_date:=start_date+ interval  '1 day';
End loop;
return start_date;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

can you tell me what is the issue with this function i was not able to execute it.I want to take all the column in select statment..please tell me                                                                                            `create or replace function insert_date_dimension("date" date)
returns setof date as $$
    declare
        dat date;
        start_date date;
        end_date date;
    begin
        start_date := '2016/01/01';
        end_date := '2016/12/31';
        while start_date <= end_date loop
            --return next  start_date;
            select start_date,date_part('week',start_date),date_part('quarter',start_date),to_char(start_date, 'day'),to_char(start_date, 'month'),
            extract(year from current_date),extract(month from current_date);
            start_date:= start_date + interval  '1 day';
        end loop;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;`

```
  ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
  HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM    instead.
  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension(date) line 11 at SQL    statement
  ********** Error **********
```

Comment: No need for a function and a loop; you can use `generate_series('2001-01-01 00:00:00', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '1day::interval)` to generate a time series.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the result of your `select` needs to be stored somewhere: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a user defined function. Just use `generate_series`:

```
select generate_series('2016/01/01'::date, '2016/12/31', '1 day');
```

But if you are just fiddling with [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) then `return next` a `setof date`

```
create or replace function insert_date_dimension("date" date)
returns setof date as $$
    declare
        dat date;
        start_date date;
        end_date date;
    begin
        start_date := '2016/01/01';
        end_date := '2016/12/31';
        while start_date <= end_date loop
            return next start_date;
            start_date := start_date + interval  '1 day';
        end loop;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

`plpgsql` is an identifier. Do not quote it.

Comment: can you tell me what is the issue with this function i was not able to execute it.

Comment: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension(date) line 11 at SQL statement

Comment: @MegharajShetty You are running the function __you__ posted not the one __I__ posted

Comment: Your function is working absolutely fine..I just modified your query as per my requirement ..I want to select week,quarter ,day name and month name along with date..

Comment: is it possible to select more than one columns in return next or select while in loop..

Comment: @MegharajShetty As I posted you need to `return next`

Comment: I used return text but error ERROR:  query "SELECT start_date,date_part('week',start_date),date_part('quarter',start_date),to_char(start_date, 'day'),to_char(start_date, 'month'),
            extract(year from current_date),extract(month from current_date)" returned 7 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension(date) line 11 at RETURN NEXT